# How can I calculate the midpoint between three points using accurate variables like Horizontal accuracy and HDOP

Tags: gps, accuracy

I have three (3) points with the following fields:

- X
- Y
- Horizontal Accuracy
- Vertical Accuracy
- PDOP
- HDOP
- VDOP

And I would like to calculate the midpoint between these three points, using accurate variables like *Horizontal accuracy* and *HDOP* and define the point that contributes more and less to the midpoint.

[image]

The following example of code shows my actual implementation. Still, I would like to know if it is possible to add the haversine formula or other formula that involves horizontal accuracy and HDOP.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

latitud = [48.417398, 48.416939, 48.416243]
longitud = [-123.374056, -123.373133, -123.373485]
HDOP = [2.234, 5.214, 5.434]
HDOP = [i**-1 for i in HDOP]

lat = 0
lon = 0
down = 0

for i in range(3):    
    lat += latitud[i]*HDOP[i]
    lon += longitud[i]*HDOP[i]
    down += HDOP[i]
    
result_lat = lat/down
result_lon = lon/down

plt.scatter(longitud, latitud)
plt.scatter(result_lon, result_lat)
plt.scatter(sum(longitud)/len(longitud), sum(latitud)/len(latitud))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Hello @Vince, my question is: how can I calculate the Midpoint between three points using accurate variables like Horizontal accuracy and HDOP ?

Comment: Please [Edit] your Question to contain a question, and to answer the questions "What have you tried?' and "Where are you stuck?".

Comment: Hello @Vince, I have updated my question. I hope now it is more accurate